# Celery : starting PeriodicTask after starting worker

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, celery, worker, periodic-task

I'm working with Celery http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

I need to run a periodic tasks at a specific moment. But I only want to start my task after starting the celery worker.

For that I'm trying to create my own "PeriodicTask". But I'm dealing with a problem.

When I'm starting the worker and executing the **run_tasks.py** in another terminal, it seems that my periodic tasks is executed only one time.

How could I do to have my periodic task running every 3 seconds.

Here is a part of the code.

**Start celery :**

```
celery worker --app=worker_manager.celery  --loglevel=info
```

file **tasks.py**

```
class MyPeriodicTask(PeriodicTask):

    name = "periodic-task"
    run_every = timedelta(seconds=3)

    def run(self, **kwargs):

        logger = self.get_logger(**kwargs)
        logger.info("Running periodic task!")
```

file **run_tasks.py**

```
tasks.register(MyPeriodicTask)

wmi_collector_task = worker_app.tasks[MyPeriodicTask.name]
```

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 1):

To run periodic tasks you need to start celery beat. You can do this by passing -B argument when starting workers:

```
celery worker -B --app=worker_manager.celery --loglevel=info
```

Comment: Thanks. When I add the option -B I have my periodic task executed on starting the worker. How could I do to run the task inside the run_tasks.py